# Textview getting clipped in GridView

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am learning how to use gridview and started working on a sample app to build a basic calculator.

The idea was to use gridview to hold cells. The gridview uses a TextAdapter (extends BaseAdapter) which returns a TextView corresponding to the position passed.

I can setup everything to display numbers from 0-9 as of now but the textview seems clipped at right. This is the problem i am facing

[image]

Here are my XMLs

MainActivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:textAlignment="center">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/calculatorCellsView"

        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"

        android:numColumns="5"
        android:columnWidth="20dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

cellLayoutOfGridView xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/id_gridCell"
        android:background="@drawable/view_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

drawable background to draw border

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <stroke android:color="#000000" android:width="4dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/background_material_light"/>
    <padding android:bottom="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp" android:top="4dp"/>
</shape>
```

I found that the problem was in the Adapter's getView() function's definition overriding the layoutparams. removing  that from java file fixed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the LinearLayout if you don't use it.

**cellLayoutOfGridView.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/id_gridCell"
    android:background="@drawable/view_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

You can see what is causing the View inside grid cell to be pushed to the right. 

For KitKat: go to **Settings > Developer options > Show layout bounds**

For Lollipop: go to **Settings > Developer options > Show layout boundaries**.

Reopen your app. Now you can see view margins and paddings.

You can also post here a screenshot if you didn't find the problem.

Comment: I update my answer. Try to add `android:layout_gravity="center"`

Comment: I added some more instructions. See the answer.

Comment: I found the problem in java code - my method was overriding layourparams for the textview. I have added it to your answer and marked as correct. I hope you dont have any problem with that :)